# How to pass correct JSON to contoller in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I can't figure out why I'm get HTTP 415 when pass POST request to `http://localhost:8080/company`

My JSON in POST request

```
{
    "id" : 7,
    "name" : "IBM"
}
```

Here is my method in controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/company")
public class CompanyController {

    @Autowired
    CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Collection<Company> getAll() {
        return companyRepository.getCompanies();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,
                    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String add(@RequestBody Company company) {
        companyRepository.save(company);
        return "redirect:/company";
    }
}
```

And my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Collection<Employee> employees;
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

UPD:

Response msg: `The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method`

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting a 406? 405 doesn't match the error message. Or 415?

Comment: Sorry, `HTTP Status 415` of course.

Answer (score 6):

You'll notice your method is annotated with

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

The `consumes` is a restriction for the `@RequestMapping` saying that this method will only handle requests that have a `Content-Type` of `application/json`. Your request doesn't seem to have that header. You need to add it.